# Корректно ли использовать блок ensure для вызова pg_advisory_unlock?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Может ли запрос в рельсу завершиться так что в пуле коннектов к бд останется какой-то неосвобождённый лок?

В частности, может ли руби упасть так чтоблок ensure не вызовется и при этом коннект к базе закрыт не будет?

Answer (score 1):

Если мы подразумеваем под "руби упадёт" завершение процесса, то ОС закроет все открытые соединения автоматически, соответственно закроется сессия в postgresql и postgresql разблокирует блокировку.

Гораздо хуже, если ruby "зависнет" и будет удерживать блокировку. Но от этого не застрахована ни одна программа, ни на одном языке программирования.

В целом, можно считать использование pg_advisory_unlock в блоке ensure достаточно безопасным.

Comment: Я кажется нашел способ оставить неосвобожденный лок в работающем руби-процессе. Нужно из одного треда вызвать эксепшн в другом треде в момент выполнения блока ensure. тогда тред "упадет" а лок останется. Еще не пробовал, но должно сработать